# How to send muliple SMS through SMPP using Inetlab.SMPP v. 1.0, 30 days Evaluation version.

Tags: .net, asp-classic, smpp

I am creating a asp .net project to implement SMPP using Inetlab.SMPP v. 1.0, 30 days Evaluation version. I am able to send single massage successfully, but when try to send multiple massages,i does not send. It shows the success response but recipient not receiving any SMS. I want to know is it due to Evaluation Version's limitation or my implementation mistake. here is the method which i am using

```
client.PrepareSubmit(SubmitMode.ShortMessage, 0, 1, "ABCDEF", destination, DataCodings.UCS2, "TEXT");
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what destination is in your code. I suspect `destination` is a string, in which case you're using [this overload](http://www.inetlab.com/Help/Inetlab.SMPP/html/M_Inetlab_SMPP_SmppClient_PrepareSubmit_1.htm).

There's a different overload that takes a `List<string>` for sending to multiple recipients, documented [here](http://www.inetlab.com/Help/Inetlab.SMPP/html/M_Inetlab_SMPP_SmppClient_PrepareSubmit_3.htm).

There's an example of how to send to multiple recipients on the [FAQ page](http://www.inetlab.com/Help/Inetlab.SMPP/html/910a3293-b5b3-47a4-8e43-6d3844516be1.htm):

```
List<DestinationAddress> msisdnList = new List<DestinationAddress>(); 

DestinationAddress da1 = new DestinationAddress(); 
da1.Address = "11111111111"; 
da1.Npi = byte.Parse(tbDestAdrNPI.Text); 
da1.Ton = byte.Parse(tbDestAdrTON.Text); 
msisdnList.Add(da1); 

DestinationAddress da2 = new DestinationAddress(); 
da2.Address = "22222222222"; 
da2.Npi = byte.Parse(tbDestAdrNPI.Text); 
da2.Ton = byte.Parse(tbDestAdrTON.Text); 
msisdnList.Add(da2); 

List<SubmitMulti> sMulti = client.PrepareSubmit(SubmitMode.ShortMessage, byte.Parse(tbSrcAdrTON.Text), byte.Parse(tbSrcAdrNPI.Text), tbSrcAdr.Text, msisdnList, DataCodings.UCS2, tbSend.Text); 
client.SubmitAsync(sMulti);
```

Comment: I am already doing in same way and also try your code, but same response.Shows Successful but not delivered to msisdn.